# Entity Framework Many to Many issues while fetching data

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, many-to-many

I have two simple classes

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Roles = new Collection<Role>();
    }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public Role()
    {
        Users = new Collection<User>();
    }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I have seeded it with the following data by overriding the seed method

```
        var firstUser = new User {UserName = "vivekr"};
        var secondUser = new User {UserName = "vivekm"};

        var firstRole = new Role {RoleName = "admin"};
        var secondRole = new Role {RoleName = "user"};

        firstUser.Roles.Add(firstRole);
        firstUser.Roles.Add(secondRole);

        secondUser.Roles.Add(firstRole);


        context.Users.Add(firstUser);
        context.Users.Add(secondUser);
```

Mapping is done by overriding OnModelCreating()

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasMany<Role>(r=> r.Roles)
                .WithMany(u => u.Users)
                .Map(c=>
                         {
                             c.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                             c.MapRightKey("RoleId");
                             c.ToTable("UserRoles");
                         });
        }
```

All tables are created correctly and I can see that the values are correct(including mappings)

But I there are issues when fetching the data

If I do(assuming that db is an instance of my Context class)

```
var selectedRoles = db.Users.Find(1).Roles;
```

I get the count of selectedRoles to be 0. It is supposed to be 2. I have no idea why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Include().  When you use include you can't use find anymore.  Try something like this:

db.Users.Include("Roles ").FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == 1).Roles;

Entity framework will not automatically load related objects for you.  You have to tell it to do so by eagerly fetching like above or by using lazy load.

[Here is a good article that explains different techniques for pulling in related data.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh205756.aspx)